# prevent scrolling to top on background change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a few div layer with background images. i want to change the backgroundimage with

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
  $('#div1').css("background-image", "url(images/newBG.jpg)");
});
```

this works fine. Problem is, when im clicking the Button the Browser jumps to the top! I want to prevent that, means the scrolling is at the same position as before!

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks Ted

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

return false to prevent default action

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
  $('#div1').css("background-image", "url(images/newBG.jpg)");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: The default action of a button shouldn't be to jump back to the top, unless there is some other JS sniffing that click or the button is a server-side control with a postback - right?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel i think that button is anchor

Comment: anyways, it works guys! thank you so much!
i dont know if im allowed to post another question in this thread but, how can i make it possible to fade to the other background image, not just poping up! dont know where ive to put the .show()!Thanks

Comment: If that is the case, then it is not actually a button. @TedMosby - can you post your html?

Comment: if this is actually a `<button>`, without any `<a>` it will not scroll to top, unless it have other js event handlers

Comment: it is a <a> tag, just with the id button! but have a look at the other question, it would be awesome!

Comment: it does, as i said before! i just want to know additionally where i should put the "show();" or "animate();" to make it display with fade!

Comment: to animate background you have to ways - simulate this using two divs or use transaction, please note that it better 1st to load image to cache using `new Image()` ask another question and I will help

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bZJ8x/) demostrate problem OP has

Comment: @TedMosby css transition also can help:  http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bZJ8x/2/, don't forget to accept

Comment: sorry but i dont really get it, isnt it possible to do with animatein api of jquery?

Comment: @TedMosby, why are you nesting an anchor tag inside of a button?